# В чем ошибка (ругается на view.) подчеркивает красным

Tags: java, android

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Меню:")
                .setMessage("Ваш счет:"+score)


                .setNeutralButton("Назад в игру", null)

                .setPositiveButton(" Начать заново", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                    {
                        Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim);
                        view.startAnimation(animAlpha);
                        recreate();
                    }
                }).create().show();

    }
```

Comment: нажмите Ctrl+Enter и среда сама вам скажет, что ей не нравится. я попробую проявить свою экстрасенскую силу, и предположить, что среда хочет сделать `final view` или что-то в таком же духе

Answer (score 0):

От какого класса вы наследуетесь и что там сделано в этом классе (я не экстрасенс)?
Если от активити, то там нет значения в onBackPressed().

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`view` - это в данном случае тот объект, который вы будете анимировать.

Так как в вашем примере это диалог, и Вы хотите анимировать именно его, то стоит сделать следующее:
вместо `view.startAnimation(animAlpha);` необходимо написать **`arg0.startAnimation(animAlpha);`**, так как `arg0` в Вашем случае, это объект класса `DialogInterface` - диалог, который нужно анимировать.

**В кратце**

Попробуйте заменить **view** на **arg0**.

Comment: теперь ругается на startAnimation